# PHP - Codeigniter - Can't fill variables with post request

Tags: php, codeigniter

I am new to PHP and Codeigniter. Actualy, I'm a windows programmer wich want to explore the open source world.
I'm trying to make a website with bacoffice in PHP with Codeigniter Framework.
Right now I'm trying to register users on database that can logon on the system later.
But I can't get the data written in text box fields on my form and pass it to my variables.

Here is my controller:

```
public function InsertUser(){

        $this->load->model('sdcadmin/loginmodel');

        if($this->input->post()){

            $nome = $this->input->post('Nome') ? $this->input->post('Nome') : null; 
            $email = $this->input->post('Email') ? $this->input->post('Email') : null; 
            $utlIns = 'Sistema';
            $dataIns = getdate(1);
            $utlAlt = 'Sistema';
            $dataAlt = getdate(1);
            $senha = $this->input->post('Senha') ? $this->input->post('Senha') : null; 
            $repeteSenha = $this->input->post('Senharep') ? $this->input->post('Senharep') : null; 


                if($senha != $repeteSenha){
                    echo 'Passwords doesn't match!';
                }
                else
                {
                    $this->loginmodel->InsertUser($nome, $email, $senha, $utlIns, $dataIns, $utlAlt, $dataAlt);

                    echo 'Success!';
                }
        }
        else
        {
            echo 'Not Working';
        }  
    }
```

And here is my form:

```
<form method="POST" action="Login/InsertUser">
        <img src="<?php echo base_url() ?>Images/logo.png"/>
        <div>
            <input type="text" placeholder="Nome" required="" id="Nome" />
        </div>
        <div>
            <input type="text" placeholder="Email" required="" id="Email" />
        </div>
        <div>
            <input type="password" placeholder="Palavra-Passe" required="" id="Senha" />
        </div>
        <div>
            <input type="password" placeholder="Repetir Palavra-Passe" required="" id="Senharep" />
        </div>
        <div>
            <input type="submit" value="Registar" id="btnSub" />
        </div>
    </form>
```

In my investigation about this issue, it can be my .htaccess file that is blocking all POST request, but i'm not sure.

Here is my .htaccess file:

```
    <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On

RewriteBase /dcm/

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^system.*
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?/$1 [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^application.*
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?/$1 [L]

RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|images|robots\.txt)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L]


#This code was added in atemp to allow posts request, but not working
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_METHOD} POST
# allow localhost
RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} !127\.0\.0\.1$   
RewriteRule ^ - [F] 


</IfModule>

<IfModule !mod_rewrite.c>
ErrorDocument 404 /index.php
</IfModule>
```

Can you help me please?

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add the "name" attribute to each input type field.

```
        <div>
            <input type="text" placeholder="Nome" required="" id="Nome" name="Nome" />
        </div>
        <div>
            <input type="text" placeholder="Email" required="" id="Email" name="Email" />
        </div>
        <div>
            <input type="password" placeholder="Palavra-Passe" required="" id="Senha" name="Senha"/>
        </div>
        <div>
            <input type="password" placeholder="Repetir Palavra-Passe" required="" id="Senharep" name="Senharep" />
        </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You missed to add add name attribute to your input fields. Check below and correct it.

```
<div>
        <input type="text" placeholder="Nome" required="" id="Nome" name="Nome" />
    </div>
    <div>
        <input type="text" placeholder="Email" required="" id="Email" name="Email" />
    </div>
    <div>
        <input type="password" placeholder="Palavra-Passe" required="" id="Senha" name="Senha"/>
    </div>
    <div>
        <input type="password" placeholder="Repetir Palavra-Passe" required="" id="Senharep" name="Senharep" />
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Add name attribute to your input fields.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I'm feeling silly right now.
I thought it was mapped by Id, and not from the Name atribute.
You are all right.

It worked!

Thanks!